# How to style a functional stateless component in Reactjs using classes object

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, jsx

I want to write and style [a functional stateless component in ReactJs as described here](https://javascriptplayground.com/functional-stateless-components-react/).

```
const MyBlueButton = props => {
  const styles = { background: 'blue', color: 'white' };  
  return <button {...props} style={styles} />;
};
```

The problem is that I want to add in some [styles from stateful components as described here](https://material-ui.com/demos/lists/).

```
const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    width: '100%',
    maxWidth: 360,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
  },
});
```

The problem is that when I try to do something like this:

```
<div className={classes.root}>
```

I get the error:

> 'classes' is not defined  no-undef

How do I access the `withStyles` `classes` object to style `root` the way I want?

Comment: Do you want to use `react-jss` library here?

Comment: Oh, sorry. `material-ui` is in the tags, so issue is not `react-jss`. But still, I don't get the question very well :) Do you want to use `material-ui` with a functional component? I don't know `material-ui` much but have tried it and get the `classes` from the props?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If I understood right here is how you can do this with a functional component.

```
const styles = theme => ( {
  root: {
    width: "100%",
    maxWidth: 360,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
  },
} );

const App = ( props ) => {
  const { classes } = props;
  return <div className={classes.root}>Foo</div>;
};

export default withStyles( styles )( App );
```